# re-install hp dc7600

Tags: hp, bios, reinstall

I inherited a used hp/compaq dc7600 desktop after we upgraded at work.  The hard disk was re-formatted but it came with a set of HP XP and Restore disks - unfortunately for a dc5800.  I optimistically ran the automated format and install of XP.  It seemed to work, then asked me to reboot.

On reboot it returned to CD, so I messed with the bios so it reboots from HD.  Now it refuses to boot from hard disk.

Do I need correct disks to get this working?  Am I missing a step or trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call HP in your country and explain the situation, very often their CDs have hardware specific drivers which can be slipstreamed into OEM disks but for the sake of a call they may well send you out replacements.